# Searching for a cheap low-friction rotary encoder

Tags: resistors

I am currently building a weatherstation with an ESP32. For the wind direction measurement I have planned to use a windvane and measure its angle (where 0° = N) with a rotary enconder. A precision of 1 deg would be good. I have some rotary enconders, which would be suitable for that job, but unfortunately they all have a lot of mechanical friction (or lock quite firmly after every step).
I wanted to know if anybody knows a suitable rotary enconder?

Price below 10 dollars, would be great, too.

Comment: What is an "enconder"?

Comment: You could make your own. There are plenty of articles on how to do so. I suggest starting out with a resolution more like 15° and you can refine the design from there.

Comment: Do you have enough ADC pins left on the ESP32 to use an [Angle Sensor](http://uk.farnell.com/nxp/kmz60-115/angle-sensor-aec-q100-5-5v-soic/dp/2776020?MER=bn_level5_5NP_EngagementRecSingleItem_1#)? You could stick a bar magnet on the end of the shaft of the wind vane.

Comment: You need an "absolute encoder" not an incremental type. You can find magnetic ones for about $25-30 one-off from distributors (12-bit). Not sure how easy they are to weatherproof.

Comment: I used a 360° potentiometer (continuous rotation) with a MCP3021 I2C A/D to do this job. However, I opted for much less resolution - I don't think wind flow is sufficiently steady for better than 5° steps.

Answer (score 3):

"A precision of 1 deg would be good. I have some rotary enconders, which would be suitable for that job, but unfortunately they all have a lot of mechanical friction (or lock quite firmly after every step)."

Well, no, you don't have some suitable encoders. If your encoders have detents they have MUCH less resolution than you need.

You're looking for at least a 9-bit encoder (512 steps), since an 8-bit encoder will only have 256 steps per revolution, which is less than the 360 your 1 degree resolution requires.

Unless you can find surplus units, or get lucky finding a salvageable encoder from a junked piece of equipment, you are out of luck looking for under 10 bucks. By at least a factor of 5.